# How to fix error when running Elasticsearch 7.4?

Tags: macos, elasticsearch

When I run `elasticsearch` from the console I get the following output:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: starting java failed with [1]
output:
[0.003s][error][logging] Error opening log file 'logs/gc.log': No such file or directory
[0.003s][error][logging] Initialization of output 'file=logs/gc.log' using options 'filecount=32,filesize=64m' failed.
error:
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
Invalid -Xlog option '-Xlog:gc*,gc+age=trace,safepoint:file=logs/gc.log:utctime,pid,tags:filecount=32,filesize=64m', see error log for details.
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
    at org.elasticsearch.tools.launchers.JvmErgonomics.flagsFinal(JvmErgonomics.java:111)
    at org.elasticsearch.tools.launchers.JvmErgonomics.finalJvmOptions(JvmErgonomics.java:79)
    at org.elasticsearch.tools.launchers.JvmErgonomics.choose(JvmErgonomics.java:57)
    at org.elasticsearch.tools.launchers.JvmOptionsParser.main(JvmOptionsParser.java:89)
```

Notes:
- Just reinstalled Elasticsearch with homebrew
- Elastic search v 7.4

What could be the problem?

Comment: Is there anything in the error message that seems unclear?

Comment: there is a folder /logs  ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue here looks to be `logs/gc.logs` not resolving to a full path. Try specifying a full log path like `/usr/local/var/log/elasticsearch/gc.log` or `/var/log/elasticsearch/gc.log` in `jvm.options`

Have a look at [this](https://github.com/elastic/windows-installers/issues/249#issuecomment-523078332) thread.

Comment: I did this and then installed the latest version of java ```brew cask install java``` and then was able to run ```elasticsearch```. Thanks!

Comment: Make sure file permissions are correct. If it can't access the log file, the same issue will present itself.